Understanding Script's number encoding, CScriptNum
What is a simple explanation of CScriptNum, the number encoding used by arithmetic opcodes in Bitcoin Script?
What would an illustrative pseudocode/python example look like?
What should the encoding of the following integers be (in hexadecimal)?

42
88
257
17000
8589934592

When is it not 4 bytes?

See Also:
Why are arithmetic script opcodes limited to 4 byte operands?
Arithmetic operations in Bitcoin (OP_ADD, etc)
Compact integer in Scripts

Numbers in Script are represented as byte vectors of up to 4 bytes and interpreted as signed integers between -2^31+1 and 2^31-1. This is with the exception of OP_0, OP_1NEGATE and OP_1 through OP_16 which allow to represent small numbers (from -1 to 16) by using opcodes directly.
These 31 bits numbers are encoded in little-endian with sign-magnitude. Note the byte vector size is not fixed: there is no padding for small integers. Here is a few examples.



Integer
Script byte vector




-424242
[0x32; 0x79; 0x86]


-0x80
[0x80; 0x80]


-1
[0x81]


0
[]


12
[0x0c]


0x82
[0x82; 0x00]


2^31-1
[0xff; 0xff; 0xff; 0x7f]



The reference implementation of the serialization can be found here. The Bitcoin Core test framework has a Python reimplementation of the serialization. Here is a simplified and highly commented version:
def ser_script_num(n):
    res = bytearray()

    # If n is 0, return the empty vector.
    if n == 0:
        return bytes(res)

    # Encode n as little-endian. Done manually to avoid padding.
    abs_n = abs(n)
    while abs_n > 0:
        res.append(abs_n & 0xff)
        abs_n >>= 8

    # If n is negative and the serialized number does not have its most significant
    # bit set, we can just set it by adding 0x80 to its most significant byte. This
    # avoids requiring an additional byte just to set the sign bit.
    msb_set = res[len(res) - 1] >= 0x80
    if not msb_set and n < 0:
        res[len(res) -1] += 0x80

    # However it does mean that if the serialized number has its most significant
    # bit set we need to push an additional byte so 1) it's not treated as negative
    # if it's positive 2) it's not substracted from its actual value.
    if msb_set:
        # If n is positive add a byte so the sign bit isn't set. If it's negative add
        # another byte for the sign bit so it's not substracted from the number itself.
        if n >= 0:
            res.append(0x00)
        else:
            res.append(0x80)

    return bytes(res)

